# Javascript/jquery .load passing variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Stuck on a jquery/javascript function that is attempting to .load a set PHP script but passing get variable parameters.  As an aside this is set to happen automatically after 5 seconds.  New to posting here but have read a lot of posts and can't seem to find exactly what I am doing wrong.

**This function works:**

```
function LoadMyPhpScript()
{
    $('#MyDiv').load('hello.php');
}
setTimeout(LoadMyPhpScript,5000);
```

**This function does not work:**

```
function LoadMyPhpScript2(cPhpParamString)
{
    var strURL = 'hello.php';
    strURL = strURL + cPhpParamString;
    $('#MyDiv2').load(strURL);
}
setTimeout(LoadMyPhpScript2('?MyVar1=0&MyVar2=1'),5000);
```

**Here's the hello.php**

```
<?php
echo '<p>Hello, I am loaded with get values of MyVar1=' . $_GET['MyVar1'] . ', MyVar2=' . $_GET['MyVar2'] . '</p>';
?>
```

Note: this is just a mock-up, would use regex to validate gets, etc in production.

**RESOLVED**

Here is what I ended up with, thank you!

```
function LoadMyPhpScript1(cPhpParamString)
{
    $('#MyDiv1').load('hello.php'+cPhpParamString);
}
setTimeout(function() { LoadMyPhpScript1('?MyVar1=0&MyVar2=1'); },5000);
```

Comment: Why are you using camelCase in your url? Try doing this with lowercase only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
LoadMyPhpScript2('?MyVar1=0&MyVar2=1')
```

You are executing the function and passing the result to `setTimeout`

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { LoadMyPhpScript2('?MyVar1=0&MyVar2=1'); },5000);
```

However, sending the url querystring like that is an odd way of doing it. Something like this might be better:

```
function LoadMyPhpScript2(myVar1, myVar2)
{
    var strURL = 'hello.php';
    $('#MyDiv2').load(strURL, { myVar1: myVar1, myVar2: myVar2 });
}
setTimeout(function() { LoadMyPhpScript2(0, 1); },5000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Neither of these seem to yield the desired result of having values passed via GET to the PHP.

Comment: What are you seeing? The text in the php file minus the values?

Comment: Yes, I'm wanting to post the entire code updated but can't seem to find the proper way to do that.  I can maybe edit original?

Comment: Go ahead and update your question. Leave the old code, but add the new below it.

Comment: All set (see edit), thank you for the assist.  Posting here is a little intimidating and I appreciate the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Better try this way:

File help3.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function LoadMyPhpScript2(cPhpParamString)
    {
        var strURL = 'help3.php';
        strURL = strURL + cPhpParamString;

      $.ajax({
      url: strURL
      }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
       $('#MyDiv').html(data); // display data
      });


    }
    setTimeout(LoadMyPhpScript2('?MyVar1=0&MyVar2=1'),5000); 

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div id="MyDiv">

      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

File help3.php:

```
<?php
echo '<p>Hello, I am loaded with get values of MyVar1=' . $_GET['MyVar1'] . ', MyVar2=' . $_GET['MyVar2'] . '</p>';
?>
```

Test on my localhost, and both files on the same folder.